# stacks process_radtags in snakemake 7.32.4

Tags: python, stack, pipeline, snakemake

I have been trying to convert my SLURM scripts to snakemake, which I am not too familiar with. I have paired-end reads from 5 pools. Each set of fastqz's is in it's own directory by pool. Here is my current code. I continue to get an error that I am missing output files, but can't figure out why.

```
RUNPOOLS, POOLS = glob_wildcards('/mnt/lz01/mel/cld1061/AScott_Data/raw_data/{runpool}/{pool}_R1_001.fastq.gz')

rule all:
    input:
        expand('02demulti_output/{runpool}/{runpool}.1.fq.gz', runpool=RUNPOOLS),
        expand('02demulti_output/{runpool}/{runpool}.2.fq.gz', runpool=RUNPOOLS),
        expand('10-logs/process_radtags/{runpool}.log', runpool=RUNPOOLS)

### demultiplexing
rule demultiplex:
    input:
        fastq_r1=expand('/mnt/lz01/mel/cld1061/AScott_Data/raw_data/{runpool}/{pool}_R1_001.fastq.gz', runpool=RUNPOOLS, pool=POOLS),
        fastq_r2=expand('/mnt/lz01/mel/cld1061/AScott_Data/raw_data/{runpool}/{pool}_R2_001.fastq.gz', runpool=RUNPOOLS, pool=POOLS)
    output:
        directory('02demulti_output/{runpool}'),
    '02demulti_output/{runpool}/{runpool}.1.fq.gz',
    '02demulti_output/{runpool}/{runpool}.2.fq.gz',
        '10-logs/process_radtags/{runpool}.log'
    log:
        '10-logs/process_radtags/{runpool}.log'
    shell:
        '''mkdir -p {output[0]};
    module load anaconda/colsa
    conda activate stacks-2.5
        process_radtags -P -i gzfastq -1 {input.fastq_r1} -2 {input.fastq_r2} -o {output[0]} -b ../01-info_files/barcodes.txt -r -D --index_null --disable_rad_check --retain_header --barcode_dist_1 1 2> {log}'''
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Several comments:

- for outputs, you shouldn't list logs (in rule all or the individual rules).  Those are produced as a side effect not a direct target
- you should only need to use `directory` output if you can't list the actual files before (like in a scatter operation where you don't know the outputs).  Snakemake will create parent directories of outputs for you.
- I think your error is because `expand` uses all combinations of wildcards and here you will likely need to pass it `zip`.  This is a common question that you can find in the documentation.

I'll also post my workshop material on converting slurm scripts to snakemake pipelines, hope it helps! https://github.com/troycomi/snakemake-training